# What's the best way to increment a number of a class or id?

Tags: templating

I have the following code which works fine. I'm just wondering if there is a more simple way of incrementing the id number?

```
{% set counter = '1' %}
{% for block in entry.news %}
  {% if block.type == "bodyBlock" %}
    {{ block.body }}
  {% elseif block.type == "codeBlock" %}
  {% set counter = counter + 1%}
    <div id="accordion{{ counter }}">
    ...
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using the [*default* filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) you can get away with a single line of Twig to set *and* increment the counter:

```
{% for block in entry.news %}
    {% if block.type == "bodyBlock" %}
        {{ block.body }}
    {% elseif block.type == "codeBlock" %}
        {% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 1 %}
        <div id="accordion{{ counter }}">
            ...
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, I'm guessing you need the accordion elements to be chronologically numbered, but if you *don't*, you can use the `index` property of the [loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable), which is available inside the `for` loop:

```
{% for block in entry.news %}
    {% if block.type == "bodyBlock" %}
        {{ block.body }}
    {% elseif block.type == "codeBlock" %}
        <div id="accordion{{ loop.index }}">
            ...
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yup I did need them to be chronological. Thanks so much for your answer. Worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple `counter++` in twig, so your solution is a good way to handle this. What are you trying to do with the counter variable? There are other functions in twig like [cycle](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/cycle.html) that are often useful in these situations.